# Backbone.js get propertys from different ressource for model entry

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I try to generate a Backbone Collection with values from 2 different Rest Services. I got 1 Rest Service which gives me a list with General Propertys for example:

```
{["id":"31", "folder":"fid3223"]}
{["id":"12", "folder":"fid2323"]}
```

I fetch them in a collection, now I want for every Model to get his Propertys, which I only get from another rest Ressource by his id. And I want to safe them in that collection like this:

```
{["id":"31", "folder":"fid3223", propertys["prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2","prop3":"value3"]]}
{["id":"12", "folder":"fid2323",propertys["prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2","prop3":"value3"]]}
```

is ther an easy way to implement this using backbone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think that your "model" which fetch from Rest Service 1 should look like this:

```
{"id":"31","folder":"fid3223"}
{"id":"32","folder":"fid2323"}
```

One object represents one list item right?

And your merged collection should looks like this:

```
[{"id":"31","folder":"fid3223","propertys":{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2","prop3":"value3"}}
```

You want to merge these two Rest service data into one collection. Backbone fetch method will perform "smart" fetch when your data had set unique id attribute. So you could fetch Rest1 service into collection and dynamical change its url property to Rest2 url then fetch again. The same id list data will be merged.

Simple example:

**Model:**

```
var List = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
```

**Collection:**

```
var Lists = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: List,
    url:"ur/url/to/rest1"
});

var lists = new Lists();
```

**View:** (checkItem function will help you to see what happen to models in ur collection)

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#list-view",
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(lists,"add",this.checkItem);
        this.listenTo(lists,"change",this.checkItem);
    },
    checkItem: function(model){
        console.dir(model);
});

var listView = new ListView();

$("#basic-btn").click(function(){
    lists.fetch();
});

$("#property-btn").click(function(){
    lists.url = "ur/url/to/rest2";
    lists.fetch();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--backbone-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone/backbone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="basic-btn">load basic</button>
<button id="property-btn">load property</button>
<ul id="list-view">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

First I click "basic-btn" and will get this result:

[image]

Then I click "property-btn" and properties will be merged into exist list item:

[image]

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I forgot to say that I have to get the Properties for every single Element. That means i have to do a single rest call vor every model in my collection. with the id of the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for merging your `Model`s attributes.

After you got the data from the server, you could do something like this:

```
var models = [ {..}, {..} ]; // Two javascript objects holding the attributes, let's assume these are from the second fetch
collection.set(models, { merge: true }); // Here Backbone will look for existing objects in that collection and merge their attributes
```

How you're fetching the data is another thing.
If it's using the `fetch()` method that Backbone provides, and the new attributes are inside the `propertys` you should override the collection's `parse()` method... Consult Backbone's documentation.